# How to use image:fixed, z-index and scroll-over effects

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, background-position

I'm wondering whether anyone is able to tell me how to use similar image effects,etc. to those on http://www.handsoneveryday.com/ for the background image, info.box in the center of the page and the grey that scrolls over all of it.
I've tried using z-index and position:fixed but nothing seems to be working.
Thank you so much
-Ina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy, you can achieve this by applying following properties to your class , say `.parrallax`.

```
.parallax {
  background-image: url("PATH_OF_IMAGE");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Here is working demo -

```css
.parallax {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452723312111-3a7d0db0e024?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=650&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1375);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 40%;
  height: 300px;
}

.diffImg {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449452198679-05c7fd30f416?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=650&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1375');
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax"></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<div class="parallax diffImg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help however I was looking more to keep the same image in the background however with text,etc. scrolling over it (again like on the website I linked)... Could you possibly help with that?

Comment: Hey @Ina, I guess this is what you were looking for - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGWjdZ?editors=1100

Please don't go with colors. :D

Comment: Thank you so much- this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad that I helped!, I will create a nice Codepen of this effect  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved using a parallax effect with CSS and HTML.

It is fairly easy and the coding help can be found [here](https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/).

The example of the code to be built can be [seen here](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty example of parallax.

CSS: div positioning then a scaled 3d transform on the z axis. The z axis goes into the screen. The scaling is to prevent the layer further from you (further into the screen) from getting smaller. Since it's a 3d transform perspective is an issue.

Hope this helps.

Best,

Tim

```css
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer-lower {
  top: 100px;
}
.parallax__layer-deep {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
.parallax__layer-back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer-lower parallax__layer-back">
    Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer-deep">
    Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
  </div>
</div>
```